# Is 'zealot' not nice?

Tags: discussion

Is using ['zealot'](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/can-you-license-the-same-software-with-different-licenses-for-different-industri#comment16761_6789) in a comment a violation of the [be nice](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. Any content violates the Be Nice policy if it is, well, not nice.

I've removed that comment.

Comment: The word "zealot" by itself doesn't seem insulting (the historical zealots having been true believers and freedom fighters), but it sure depends on how it was used.